# An error occurred when move to before activity to next activity

Tags: android

I have following error when I move from an activity to a new activity.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

I inputted toolbar in next activity but not in main activity.

I think toolbar causes the error.  i don't know where the error is please advice what am i missing

activity.java

```
private void redirectMainActivity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ServiceActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

ServiceActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;



public class ServiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar;
String ClientTAG = "Client";
String OptionTAG = "Option";
private Context context = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_service);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    mToolbar.setTitle("tool test");
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I changed styles.xml and include toolbar.xml to layout_service.xml

Comment: Whats the error man?

Comment: You should include the LogCat with the error

Comment: 07-31 23:27:59.566 19463-19463/com.example.park.mykakao E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.park.mykakao, PID: 19463
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.park.mykakao/com.example.park.mykakao.ServiceActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: this is logcat. app has been shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, in order to use `Toolbar`, you must use a theme with `windowActionBar` set to false. Otherwise, you will get an error like:

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Since your first Activity does not have an Toolbar but the second one does, I think you are using same theme for both of them.

However, in Activities that you are using a Toolbar, you must use a Theme which sets `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

So, I think you can do as follows:

**Android Manifest**

Set your secondary Activity to use a different theme.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppThemePrimaryActivity">

    <activity android:name=".PrimaryActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SecondaryActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeSecondaryActivity" />
</application>
```

**styles.xml**

Create a theme with `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` for your secondary activity:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppThemePrimaryActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeSecondaryActivity" parent="AppThemePrimaryActivity">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This way, you set your secondary activity to always use a theme without default `ActionBar` and you will be able to set the `Toolbar`

Comment: Glad I could help you... regards